# Adding new members to a DbSet<Class> in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

Here is my scenario: I have a class called **Order**, which consists of basic information that should be saved in the database after that an order has been made.

In **MyPoject.Infrastructure** I use following code:

```
public class ProductDb : DbContext, IProductDataSource
{

    public ProductDb()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }


    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }


    IQueryable<Order> IProductDataSource.Orders
    {
        get
        {
            return Orders;
        }
        set
        {
            Orders = (DbSet<Order>)value;
        }
    }
}
```

In the **Controller**, I add this:

```
    private IProductDataSource _db = new ProductDb();

    public UserController(IProductDataSource db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }
```

Later on, in the **ActionResult**, where I want to add data to the order I use following:

```
var orders = _db.Orders;
var order = new Order();

//add some data to the order variable

_db.Orders.AsEnumerable().Concat(new[] { order });
_db.Save();
```

However, this does not appear to work. The problem I face is how it is possible to add new items to **Order** in the database.

EDIT:
**IProductDataSource** contains following code

```
    public interface IProductDataSource
{

    IQueryable<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }

    IQueryable<Order> Orders { get; set; }


    void Save();
    void Add();
    //void Add();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your code, it appears you are using an Interface to create an `IQueryable<Order>`, presumably to not expose the rest of your systems to Entity Framework.  However, an `IQueryable<T>` is just a special version of `IEnumerable<T>`, it still does not have access to Entity Framework features.

If you don't mind exposing your `DBset<Order>`, it is much easier to work that way since `DBSet<T>` has full support of Entity Framework behind it and supports add, delete, etc.

However, if you don't want to work with a `DBSet<T>` for some reason, you will need to create your own Add method which takes in your new `Order`, creates a temporary `DBSet<Order>`, adds the `Order` to the `DBSet`, then saves the changes.  You cannot Add directly to the `IQueryable<Order>`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this:

```
var orders = _db.Orders;
var order = new Order();

//add some data to the order variable

_db.Orders.Add(order); // order is your new Order
_db.Save();
```

Comment: I updated the code above to reflect what you had.  Maybe try wrapping it in a `try-catch` and see if an exception is being thrown.

Comment: Instead of _db.Save();, you could try _db.SaveChanges();

Comment: The problem occurs when I want to build the solution: It says: Error 1 'System.Linq.IQueryable<Order>' does not contain a definition for 'Add' and no extension method 'Add' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<Order>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: maybe I need to allow a Add when I construct the Order class

Comment: It sounds like you're missing a reference, possibly to `System.Linq`

Comment: Using the `.AsEnumerable()` creates a copy of the `Orders` object as an `IEnumerable<Order>` which is not the same as a `DBSet<Order>`.  why does `_db.Orders.Add(order)` not work? actually, I see you are using an Interface that is casting your `Dbset` as `IQueryable` which doesn't support inserts. any reason you need `IQueryable`?

Comment: I think it has to do with the interface **IProductDataSource**, since it only contains the member **Save**. However, when I added **Add** as a method, an error is thrown: Error 1 'MyProject.Infrastructure.ProductDb' does not implement interface member 'MyProjectIProductDataSource.Add()'

Comment: What do you need `IProductDataSource` for?  It seems redundant.  Just use the `ProductDb`

Comment: did you create an actual `Add()` method or just a signature for it in your Interface? See my answer.